# Consulta SQL Server que retorne valores null cuando corresponde

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, base-de-datos, mssql

tengo una pequeña duda
tengo 2 tablas:
USUARIO_SUCURSAL

- id_usuario
- id_sucursal
- id_tipo_usuario

SUCURSAL

- id_sucursal
- nombre_sucursal

necesito generar una consulta para traer

- id_sucursal
- nombre_sucursal
- id_usuario
- id_sucursal
- id_tipo_usuario

según el id_usuario en nulo o con el dato correspondiente según el id_usuario.

Funciona pero necesito que se muestre los campos

- id_sucursal
- nombre_sucursal
- id_usuario
- id_sucursal
- id_tipo_usuario

siempre, tenga o no tenga datos para el id_usuario
esta es la consulta que tengo

```
       S.ID_SUCURSAL,
       S.NOMBRE_SUCURSAL, 
       NS.ID_USUARIO,
       NS.ID_SUCURSAL AS NAV_ID_SUCURSAL,
       NS.ID_TIPO_USUARIO
        FROM USUARIO_SUCURSAL AS NS 
        RIGHT JOIN SUCURSAL AS S
            ON S.ID_SUCURSAL = NS.ID_SUCURSAL 
        AND  (NS.ID_USUARIO = 64 OR NS.ID_USUARIO IS NULL)


en la consulta el id_usuario = 64 tiene datos por lo tanto funciona como debe
id_sucursal | nombre_sucursal    | id_usuario | id_tipo_usuario
5           |   Sucursal Borrado |  null      |     null   
8           |   ejemplo          | 64         |     1
11          |   Prueba 1         |  null      |   null   


Pero al buscar con el id_usuario 60 el registro "ejemplo" ya no aparece y necesito que aparezca en null
Como puedo hacer la consulta para que funcione?
```

Comment: y porque va a aparecer, si su id_usuario no es 60, es 64????

Comment: Por eso, necesito ayuda para hacer que aparescan los registros siempre sea o no sea el id_usuario

Comment: no entiendo, le des el ID o no, debe traer ***TODO***? si es el caso, no filtres por usuario

Comment: no puede respetar el where y no respetarlo... creo que tendrias que plantear mejor que es lo que queres... no va a traer el 64, si explicitamente le decis que traiga el 60....

Comment: ¿Lo que quieres es que muestre siempre todas las sucursales exista o no el usuario en ellas? Si la respuesta es no, explica lo que quieres, no en términos de base de datos, sino en términos coloquiales.

Comment: En base a lo que dice la pregunta, quieres reemplazar todos los id's de usuario distinto al id de usuario utilizado en el where? Además de usar el left join que mencionó Dario en la respuesta, utiliza un case en el select y si es distinto al que buscas pones null. Dicho sea de paso, no le veo ningún sentido a filtrar por un usuario y traer todas las sucursales sean o no de él

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT
            S.ID_SUCURSAL,
            S.NOMBRE_SUCURSAL, 
            NS.ID_USUARIO,
            NS.ID_SUCURSAL AS NAV_ID_SUCURSAL,
            NS.ID_TIPO_USUARIO
    FROM SUCURSAL AS S
    LEFT JOIN USUARIO_SUCURSAL AS NS 
        ON S.ID_SUCURSAL = NS.ID_SUCURSAL
```

/*probaste asi?*/

Comment: Me temo que la respuesta no contesta a lo que pregunta. Lo que el quiere es que cuando en el query se indique un id de usuario ( 60 en la pregunta ), se devuelva el usuario 60 ( con los datos normal ) y también todos los demás pero con los datos en NULL.